# Extract timestamp of I-frames of video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, compression, codec

If I understand correctly, I-frames are the frames that are unaltered during video compression. I want to extract the exact timestamps of these I-frames and save the output in a txt file. How do I do this?

I found this code that saves the I-frames as images and labels them according to their frame number, but I want a txt of the timestamps:

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i ultra4k.mp4 -vsync 0 -frame_pts true out%d.png
```

`output.txt`

```
-0.366667
0.633078
1.632956
2.632756
3.632478
4.632256
5.632067
6.631844
7.631622
8.631400
9.631178
10.631000
...
```

Comment: @llogan That's my mistake. I only want a timestamp column. is .txt a better file type?

Comment: @llogan I am on a mac (catalina). I thought i-frames and key frames were interchangeable terms?

Comment: There can be non-keyframe i-frames. I'll assume you want keyframes. Use the first command from [Checking keyframe interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088156/) and append `> output.txt` to the end of the command.

Comment: @llogan Thanks I tried this. I get a txt file with the timestamps, but I am surprised. The timestamps fixed at 1 per second. Is that normal? See output in the edit.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible, although not particularly efficient. It just depends on how it was encoded and the planned use case for the file. For example, maybe whoever made it wanted finer seeking intervals. Or maybe the encoding software is just simplistic.

Comment: to extract **all** frames timestamp in ts.txt : `ffmpeg -i video.avi -f mkvtimestamp_v2 ts.txt` (I don't know for I-frames)